# How do I trigger something only when batch of getJSON instructions completes?

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, getjson

Here's some of my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < recordList.length; i++) {
  var recordID = recordList[i];
  populateDataRow(i, recordID, columns) 
};
console.log("done");
```

Here `populateDataRow` is a function that uses `$.getJSON`
The problem is (in Google Chrome at least), the `console.log` statement is triggered long before the `populateDataRow` cycles are completed

Comment: Call your "Done" method in the callback of the ajax request, and have the "Done" method only do anything when all the records have been retrieved (given that you know how many records you are expecting).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the `console.log` happens first because `getJSON` is **asynchronous**. Your code *starts* it, but it finishes later, after the subsequent code runs.

To handle that, you'll need to use the "completion" callback on `getJSON`. Your code above would remember how many calls it's started, and wait for that many completions before continuing.

You can also have your `populateDataRow` function return the return value of `getJSON`, save up those objects, and then use [`jQuery.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) to get a notification when they've all finished.

Here's an example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/aqixuh/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/aqixuh/1/edit)

```
var deferreds = [],
    index;

for (index = 0; index < 4; ++index) {
  deferreds.push($.getJSON("http://jsbin.com/agidot/1", function() {
    display("One finished");
  }));
}
$.when.apply($, deferreds).then(function() {
  display("All finished")
});

function display(msg) {
  $("<p>").html(String(msg)).appendTo(document.body);
}
```

Note that we only see "All finished" when all four calls have finished.

The call to `$.when` is a bit of a hassle. For some reason, you can't just pass an array of `Deferred` objects into it. So I used `Function#apply` to call it and pass each entry of the array as a discrete argument.

---

I was surprised that `$.when` doesn't accept an array and handle that usefully, but I see other answers here also saying to use `apply`: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4878978/157247) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7603678/157247).

If you were going to use arrays a lot, I think I'd probably have this in my standard toolkit of jQuery extensions:

```
(function($) {
    $.whenAll = function(deferreds) {
        return $.when.apply($, deferreds);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

...and then the end of the code example above would be:

```
$.whenAll(deferreds).then(function() {
  display("All finished")
});
```

Comment: very comprehensive, wonderful answer! I'll be poring over this for the rest of the day, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`$.getJSON` is a shorthand-function for jQuery's `$.ajax()`-function. 
An XHR (or AJAX) - call is asynchronous, your other code will be executed further, you'll need to provide a callback-function that is executed when the AJAX-call is completed.

From the API (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

```
$.getJSON('ajax/test.json', function(data) {

});
```

Here, `function(data){}` is the callback-function, provided as argument to `getJSON`. 
If you want to do something with the returned data, you'll need to do it in this function or after this function has been executed.

Comment: Although I didn't show it in my example, the callback is already getting used. My issue was that the getJSON instruction is called multiple times, and I only want to know when the _last_ one is run.